# HookState- Module '"@hookstate/core"' has no exported member 'useState'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, hookstate

I have 1 problem, normally it works fine, but today when I build, this error appears
Module '"@hookstate/core"' has no exported member 'useState'.
I use NextJS
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN1X5.png)

I hope to get help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You probably upgraded it to version 4. Version 4.0.0 has useHookstate instead, because useState collided with name in React and did not work in devtools.